# Is the order of tf.data.Dataset determined?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I was trying to get the y_pred from x_train, and realised that my predictions are always changing with the same model.

Then I digged a bit and found that the problem may be at `tf.data.Dataset`.

Following is how I construct the dataset:

```
test_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dirpath + '/test',
    image_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size = 32
)
```

And then I did some steps to train the model. Before I actually use the model to predict the labels, I tried to test the consistency of the test_data.

```
y_test = np.concatenate([y_test for x, y_test in test_data], axis = 0)
y_test2 = np.concatenate([y_test for x, y_test in test_data], axis = 0)
print(y_test == y_test2)
```

I was expecting for an array with all elements being True because y_test and y_test2 should be the same, while it turned out to be

```
[False False False False False  True False False True False False False ...]
```

Which means y_test and y_test2 are reading two different Dataset? Or is it simply because the Dataset is unordered and each time it reads with no order?

The same happens when I predict the label with test_data.

```
y_prob = my_model.predict(test_data)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_prob, axis=1)
```

Each time, it returns different y_pred output.

Can anyone help explain and give some guidance on how to ensure the consistency?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` [shuffles](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) your data every time you iterate over the dataset, since the argument `shuffle` is set to `True` by default. That would explain the inconsistency (assuming that the rest is correct). Try setting `shuffle=False`